# Volumetric mesh processing: impact of facet removal on connectedness?

Tags: geometry, mesh

I am working with volumetric meshes - meshes that have vertices (0-cell), edges (1-cell), facets (2-cells) and volumes (3-cells) - and I'm interested in removing facets without breaking connectedness.

**In other words, say my mesh has 1 connected component, and I don't want to remove a facet `f` if the resulting mesh has 2 (or more) connected components.**

A simple approach is to count the number of connected component with and without `f`, with a breadth/depth-first search ([wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms)). But I don't care how many components there are before or after facet removal, I just don't want this number to change. Any way of estimating the number of connected components looks like a waste of computation time.

My intuition is that a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for the removal of a facet `f` to possibly "break" connectedness is that both sides of `f` lie in the same volume, while the removal a facet `f'` whose incident volumes are two different volumes cannot modify the connectedness of the mesh.

Am I wrong ?

Below is an illustration of a case where the removal of the facet in red would result in two connected components (the little cube inside the big cube). Note that there is no 2-border in this case.

[image]